# WordPress Contact-Form 7 received mail content is empty

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

It's my contact form 7 configuration
Mail

To
bilal@truishop.com
From
[your-name] bilal@truishop.com
Subject
[your-subject]
Additional headers
Message body
From: [your-name] <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

This e-mail was sent from a contact form on [_site_title] ([_site_url])

When I received mail any content is not showing some like

From: Hammad <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

This e-mail was sent from a contact form on Bilal Asghar (https://portfolio.truishop.com)

How to resolve this issue

Comment: You need to cross check that your input name same are same in both place form as well as in mail configuration.
also please check that your contact form 7 is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input name is different than what you are using. You need to use the same input name as you are using in the form.
For your case, use below code in the message box

[your-name] bilal@truishop.com

**Subject** [subject]

Additional headers

**Message body**

From: [your-name] <[email]> Subject: [subject]

Message Body: [message]

This e-mail was sent from a contact form on [_site_title] ([_site_url])